# Amazon AWS Grey state - Deleting security group failed

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am new to AWS. After invalid deployment my environment `cloudapp` went to the Grey state. I have created another environment `cloudapp-1`and successfully uploaded and deployed my app. Then I swap the URLs to keep the first address still working.

Now when my first env is in the Grey state I am not able to do anything with it. I am not able to deploy, rebuild or even terminate it. I receive errors like this ones below.

```
Stack deletion failed: The following resource(s) failed to delete: [awseb-xxx-AWSEBSecurityGroup]. 
 2016-07-13 13:23:32 UTC+0200   ERROR   Deleting security group named: awseb-xxx-AWSEBSecurityGroup failed Reason: resource sg-xxxxxxx has a dependent object
```

I have tried to remove AWSEBSecurityGroup from `cloudapp` but i cannot because:

```
Error
Unable to validate settings: Environment named cloudapp is in an invalid state for this operation. Must be Ready.
```

It looks like kind of deadlock. I cannot delete the env because of a security group and I cannot change that group because the env is not Ready.
How to fix it?

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Posting the color of the environment is not very informative. I believe more info can be gathered from specifying the health state of your env. You can see it in the env main dashboard. What does it say there (I suspect you will find it is terminated)

Comment: I do not see anything here 'Causes' button is disabled. I only see the logs like: 2016-07-13 13:40:33 UTC+0200  ERROR  Stack deletion failed: The following resource(s) failed to delete: [AWSEBSecurityGroup].

Comment: It is not terminated. I cannot terminate it.

Comment: Could you please post a screenshot of your environment dashboard?

Comment: Do you have any EC2 instance that was creted when you launched the first environment and is that instance still running?

Comment: No the firs EC2 instance is not running. I have provided the screenshots. If you need anything more just let me know.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First make sure that no other instances than the ElasticBeanstalk EC2 instances belonging to this particular environment is using the `sg-xxxxxx` security group.

Then you must make sure that you do not have any depending objects of that security group, like the error message vaguely states. Go to `EC2 > Security Groups` and search by `Source/Destination (Group Id)` for the `sg-xxxxxx` group.

[image: screenshot from security groups in ec2]

This will give you a list of all security groups having rules referencing `sg-xxxxxx`. Once you've removed the depending rules you can retry your ElasticBeanstalk operation.

Comment: I have done it. First I copied the existing security group. Then I switched the working environment to the new one. Then I retried the operation and finally:  
`This environment is terminated and cannot be modified. It will remain visible for about an hour.`

Comment: Also make sure you don't have any EC2 instances that are linked to that security group using ClassicLink